# How do I find files in a directory that do not have extensions?

Tags: ruby

I am looking for a code that will find files without extensions. In Rails, there is a file `app_name/doc/README_FOR_APP`. I am searching for a way to find files simular to this with no extension associated to the file, i.e., 'gemfile'. Something like:

```
file = File.join(directory_path, "**", "__something__")
```

Comment: What do you define as an *extension*?

Comment: .txt, .rb. erb .js .css  blah blah blah   files like gemfile  rakefile README_FOR_APP and so on have no extensions.  I am writing a script that runs through files and comments them. so I'm looking for a way to look at all files that have no extensions and write something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your question didn't explicitly specify whether you want to search for files without extensions recursively (though in the comments it sounded like you might), or whether you would like to keep files with a leading dot (i.e. hidden files in unix), I'm including options for each scenario.

**Visible Files (non-recursive)**

```
Dir['*'].reject { |file| file.include?('.') }
```

will return an array of all files that do not contain a '.' and therefore only files that do not have extensions.

**Hidden Files (non-recursive)**

```
Dir.new('.').entries.reject { |file| %w(. ..).include?(file) or file[1..-1].include?('.') }
```

This finds all of the files in the current directory and then removes any files with a '.' in any character except the first (i.e. any character from index 1 to the end, a.k.a index -1). Also note that since `Dir.new('.').entries` contains '.' and '..' those are rejected as well.

**Visible Files (recursive)**

```
require 'find'
Find.find('.').reject { |file| File.basename(file).include?('.') }.map { |file| file[2..-1] }
```

The map on the end of this one is just to remain consistent with the others by removing the leading './'. If you don't care about that, you can remove it.

**Hidden Files (recursive)**

```
require 'find'
Find.find('.').reject { |file| File.basename(file)[1..-1].include?('.') }.map { |file| file[2..-1] }
```

Note: each of the above will also include directories (which are sometimes considered files too, well, in unix at least). To remove them, just add `.select { |file| File.file?(file) }` to the end of any one of the above.

Comment: Well, this is technically incorrect. In a file like `.htaccess` or `simple.example.noextension` there are no extensions, and it's still a valid file name.

Comment: .htaccess is actually an extension.

Comment: @EricMathison, not at all. It's an hidden file. In Unix systems files or folders prefixed by *at least* one dot are hidden.

Comment: @Jueecy.new You're correct of course, but I think this answer interprets "extension" in a looser sense that it sounded like Tony was going for.

Comment: @DarshanComputing, That's why I didn't downvote the answer. I just made him notice that it's not *technically* correct. :)

Comment: `Dir.glob(File.join(directory_path, "**", "*")).reject{|path| path.split("/").last.include?('.')}` looks like it does the trick more in depth then Erics.

Comment: @TonyLombardi, yes it does. At least it checks if its the last part that has a `.` in it. The above answer will fail with hidden folders: `/this/is/an/.example/app/file`.

Comment: @Jueecy.new Just for fun, I updated my answer to include an option that I think fits your more precise definition.

Comment: @Jueecy.new Although I do think that some systems would consider `simple.example.noextension` to have an extension of `noextension`.  And can a hidden file have an extension? `.hidden.txt`?  Ultimately it's up to Tony to do what works for his situation.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an additional technique that uses the more narrow definition of extension.

Comment: @Jueecy.new are you saying that simple.example.noextension isn't an extension because of the length of noextension or because of the intent of the person who created it? According to Wikipedia, length only matters on some file systems. I could definitely be wrong about .htaccess being considered an extension though. I was only saying that based on things I've heard. For example, take a look at the last paragraph in this page: http://www.linfo.org/filename_extension.html.

Comment: Either way, it seems many of my hidden config files (.vimrc for instance) are used as extensions, since when I open them they usually have the correct syntax highlighting.

Comment: @EricMathison, I base my statement on the fact that extensions have a purpose: give an hint on the Operating System on how (with what) to open the file. Therefore the best extension recognizer would be one that stores all real existing extensions. The problem is that such a recognizer wouldn't be always up to date and therefore wouldn't be helpful. In Unix systems the extension is really *nothing*, therefore I could easily open a random file with no extension with whatever program I have. The only problem would be how the bytes are going to be translates within that program.

Comment: The syntax highlighting is not really a proof of that. Text editors probably have a list of fixed file names (`.htaccess`, `.*rc` etc...) linked to their proper *style*. [As you can see](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess) `htaccess` *is* a file, [as well as](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_vimrc_file) `vimrc`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dir.glob(File.join(directory_path, "**", "*")).reject do |path|
  File.directory?(path) || File.basename(path).include?('.')
end
```

**Update:** If you want to take a stricter definition of "extension", here's something a little more complex that considers a file name to have an extension if and only if it has exactly one dot and that dot is neither the first nor last character in the name:

```
Dir.glob(File.join(directory_path, "**", "*")).reject do |path|
  name = File.basename(path)
  File.directory?(path) || (name.count('.') == 1 && name[-1] != '.')
end
```

I suspect "not having a dot" is more what you were looking for, however.

Comment: [+1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283744/how-do-i-find-files-in-a-directory-that-do-not-have-extensions?noredirect=1#comment23308412_16284467)

Comment: Is there a way to exclude directories in the the array?

Comment: @TonyLombardi Sure, just add `File.directory?(path)` to the rejection criteria.  I updated the more complex of my examples, but you could do the exact same thing with the first example if "doesn't have a dot" is all you need for the actual file.

Comment: @TonyLombardi Actually I figured I should update the first example, too, so I just did so.

Comment: @DarshanComputing I hope you don't mind, I edited your answer to use File.basename(path) instead of path.split(File::SEPARATOR) as it seems to be a bit shorter and more expressive.

Comment: @DarshanComputing I'm hoping you can clarify something for me in your solution. In your second example, I'm trying to understand your purpose in rejecting entries where `name[0] != '.'`. I could definitely be misunderstanding what is going on here but doesn't `Dir.glob(File.join(directory_path, "**", "*"))` already exclude hidden files beginning with a '.'?

Comment: @EricMathison Thanks for the edits. It looks like they were probably rejected as too minor before I got here, but I went in and switched to  `File.basename` -- I agree that that's nicer.  As for the initial dot, you're correct about that as well. I often have to remind myself that `*` doesn't match hidden files. I literally translated my working definition of "having an extension" to code. You're correct that that part of the condition was redundant. I've removed that as well. Thanks for the thoughtful comments!

Answer (score 0):

```
nonfile = File.join("**", "*.")
Dir.glob(nonfile).each do |path|
    puts path
end
```

I was messing around and I was talking to a colleague and we thought if this.
Wouldn't that do the trick?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `Dir.glob('**/*.')` (which is essentially what you are doing here) recursively searches for files that end with a `'.'`. For example `'foobar.'`. I don't think that is what you are looking for. I've added a few more solutions in my answer that may help you further.